# c# web API locally work, but does not work in Azure after publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, download

I got below error. I am trying to implement download WEB API in C# which downloads the blob to file from azure blob storage.

I have tried debugging mode on visual studio but it it doesn't work and return errors when tested locally only get that error on deployment. i'm guessing it might be the file path but i don't know to be honest.

> Internal Server Error 500.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/download")]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class DownloadController : ApiController
{
    private ggContext db = new ggContext();
    private const string Container = "ggblobcontainer";
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFile(int audioid)
    {
        //get the object storing the audio 
        Someobject zzz = db.Meetings.Find(audioid);
        //get the filename from the object 
        string fileName = zzz.GetFileName();
        //account information from web.config 
        var accountName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storage:account:name"];
        var accountKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storage:account:key"];
        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
        //create blob client from account
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        //get the container with the blobs storing the audio
        CloudBlobContainer audioContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(Container);
        //get the specific blob with the filename from object
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = audioContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        //if the blob is null error response
        if (blockBlob == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "blob with the file name " + fileName + " does not exist in " + Container);
        }
        try
        {
            //cause audio storage name on azure has "" eg. "sick audio file - why is it wrong [LYRICS].mp3" with quotations
            string regexSearch = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
            Regex r = new Regex(string.Format("[{0}]", Regex.Escape(regexSearch)));
            //replace illegal chars with nothing in case replace the . for .mp3 
            string CleanFileName = r.Replace(fileName, "");
            // download to desktop
            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            //change it to fileName not dragon little bits 
            string gg = Path.Combine(path, CleanFileName);
            blockBlob.DownloadToFile(gg, FileMode.Create);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, fileName + " was downloaded succesfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: The error shows that server does not know the page for execution. it means your azure configuration of iis does not map properly. are you access your method directly in local and in azure server

Comment: Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) this looks suspicious to me. Try to map the path to a server URL.

Comment: i published correctly as my other controllers work when i test other web api

Comment: Relevant code should be posted as part of your question, not as a link to an external resource. I've fixed this for you.

Comment: And @Azaz's comment is likely an accurate diagnosis.

Comment: Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop); i thought that was where i was downloading to?

Comment: The user your app runs with in Azure is very unlikely to grant you access to a desktop.

Comment: can i get an example of how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) wont work on server environment. So you have to try something like:

```
string gg = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~\SomeDirectoryName"), CleanFileName)
```

Hope this would help.